# Error $timeout in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I have controller and inside a $timeout function:

```
.controller('MapCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$log', '$timeout', function ($scope, $http, $interval, $log, $timeout) {
   $timeout(function () {
                $scope.marker.coords = {
                    latitude: 42.1451,
                    longitude: -100.6680
                };
                $scope.dynamicMoveCtr++;
                $timeout(function () {
                    $scope.marker.coords = {
                        latitude: 43.1451,
                        longitude: -102.6680
                    };
                    $scope.dynamicMoveCtr++;
                }, 2000);
            }, 1000);
}]);
```

Why it gives me error:

> typeError: $timeout is not a function
>       at new  (angularmy.js:2879)
>       at Object.e [as invoke] (angular.min.js:36)
>       at $get.x.instance (angular.min.js:75)

At another controller function `$timeout` works correct

Comment: try to order the dependencies correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.controller('MapCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$log', '$timeout', function ($scope, $http, $interval, $log, $timeout)
```

The string arguments don't match the arguments being passed to the function.

```
'$scope', '$http', '$log', '$timeout'

($scope, $http, $interval, $log, $timeout)
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to inject the $timeout parameter.

Fix it like this:

```
.controller('MapCtrl', ['$scope', '$http','$interval', '$log', '$timeout', function ($scope, $http, $interval, $log, $timeout) {
```

Comment: It is the $interval params but you are right for the fix

Comment: its work by place in array,   the last param in function($timeout)  got undefined